# Confirm password value lost during postback in zend framwork?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am working with Zend Framework. In my Zend form when there is post back or validation error all the fields contain there values but confirm password lost it's value.How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default password fields to not include the submitted value, since doing so somewhat defeats the point of obfuscating the password with *****. However you can pass the 'renderPassword' option to the password field to change this behaviour.

There's an example of usage on the patch where the feature was introduced: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2860

Comment: Thanks Tim but if i use renderPassword and when i edit user's value into edit form and inspect password value into chrome or Mozilla it show password in plain text format. How can i solve that problem do you have any idea about this problem

Comment: Unfortunately you can't have it both ways. I think you'd need to store the password in the session after the first post, and then either not display the password field when redisplaying the form or put in an arbitrary value that is ignored on submit. It'll be a fair bit of hassle though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this option.

you can get the form in view and render all elements one by one like this

and you can set value also.

`$confpassword = $this->form->getElement('confpassword');
$confpassword->setValue($_POST['confpassword']);
echo $confpassword;`